# Make "ping localhost" resolve to "127.0.0.1" instead of "::1" without the -4 option

Tags: windows-10, ip-address, loopback

## Context

We're wanting to use RawCap to inspect HTTP requests to localhost. RawCap though cannot capture IPv6. We've considered doing a massive find-replace of "localhost" with "127.0.0.1" in our project, but this is a challenge, because our configuration is distributed.

## What We Have Tried

This is our entire hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

We have run the following Fixits from "[How to disable IPv6 or its components in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929852)":

- Disable IPv6
- Prefer IPv4 over IPv6 in prefix policies
- Disable IPv6 on all nontunnel interfaces
- Disable IPv6 on all tunnel interfaces
- <s>Disable IPv6 on nontunnel interfaces (except the loopback) and on IPv6 tunnel interface</s>

We've changed the following registry key:

```
reg add hklm\system\currentcontrolset\services\tcpip6\parameters 
    /v DisabledComponents /t REG_DWORD /d 0xFF
```

Restarted the computer.

## Result

The prefixpolicies are up to date and so it nslookup. Ping is stubbornly not using IPv4; neither is Firefox when we request localhost:5000.

This is our `netsh int ipv6 show prefixpolicies` output.

```
Precedence  Label  Prefix
----------  -----  --------------------------------
       100      3  ::/96
```

This is our `nslookup localhost` output:

```
Server:  router.asus.com
Address:  192.168.1.1

Name:    localhost
Address:  127.0.0.1
```

This is our stubborn `ping localhost` output:

```
Pinging DESKTOP-AAAT5QS [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
```

Comment: Tried `reg add hklm\system\currentcontrolset\services\tcpip6\parameters /v DisabledComponents /t REG_DWORD /d 0xFF` ?

Comment: Haven't tried that @pun. What does it do?

Comment: Thats another way of disabling IPv6, see [this](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-ipv6-5-second-boot-delay)

Comment: Just tried it - I will do a reboot and see what happens.

Comment: this is somewhat same as what the fixit does but I have found fixit lying at times

Comment: @pun That did not work. Bummer.

Comment: Why wouldn't WinPcap work for you? It's a more permanent solution and much more compatible.

Comment: @oldmud0 I was under the impression that it doesn't work with IPv6. https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback and http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/articles/win_net_srv/missing_loopback.html talk about this.